# Sequentially Rename 100+ Columns Having Idiosyncratic Names

Tags: r, rename, multiple-columns, google-forms

I have a large data frame imported from a Google Forms survey with very long column names (basically, the column names are the survey questions themselves).

So, my imported data frame is like this:

```
      d<-
  data.frame(LongnameLongnameLongnameLongname=1:3,AnotherOneAnotherOneAnotherone=4:6, Etc_Etc_Etc_Etc_Etc=3:5)
      d
```

GOAL: To replace these long, idiosyncratic column names with a sequential name, such as Q1, Q2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use the colnames function:

```
colnames(d) <- paste0("Q",1:ncol(d))
```